Is using the $file system collection a valid method to programmatically import JSON files to a LiteDb LiteDatabase?
I have a collection of json files in a local folder I wish to use for seeding where the file names are the Collection names. Each file is a json array of the specified type. I have a class which a method (below) creates the db to seed, iterating over each file found, deserializing the array as a BsonDocument which I found in one of mbdavid's answers:
public async Task<LiteDatabase> SeedDbAsync(LiteDatabase db)
{
    var mapper = SetMappings();

    using (db = new LiteDatabase(_options.Filename))
    {
        foreach (var path in _paths)
        {
            var json = await _fileMap.GetFileAsync(path);
            var doc = JsonSerializer.DeserializeArray(json).Select(x => x.AsDocument);
            db.GetCollection(path.Name).InsertBulk(doc);
        }
    }

    return db;
}

I then noticed I might simplify this by using LiteDb to read in the json directly from the file, something like this:
SELECT $ FROM $FILE('customers.json')

Aside from the fewer lines of code which would be involved, are there any other advantages or disadvantages to going this route?
I have tried the initial method.
